# How on EARTH did I get a +11?

Tags: support

This is really just out of curiosity, but it turns out that I had +189 reputation yesterday.  THEN I got a +11 for a vote on a question.  As a result I got the motarboard badge.  I'm not complaining by any means, just curious.  If someone did something to help me out - thanks.

Comment: I looked at your reputation history and it seems there was one question that you earned three upvotes for: http://i.imgur.com/ObjZg.png -- the first 2 upvotes gave you 10 points each (as they should!) but the third upvote only gave you 1 reputation point. Why only 1? Beofett answers this in his post below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you downvoted an answer that same day, which gives you -1 reputation (and the person whose answer you downvoted -2.

There is a daily limit of 200 reputation that you can earn (not including reputation for bounties and accepted answers).

Reputation you lose for downvoting an answer is not shown to other users (to reduce the chances of retaliatory voting), so I can't say for certain, but I suspect you earned over 200 points of reputation that day (nice job, btw!), but only 200 points + 1 extra point to compensate for what you lost by downvoting an answer counted due to the daily cap.

Example: if you get upvotes on 30 answers in one day, you'll only get 200 reputation due to the cap.  If you then downvote an answer, you'll be at 199 reputation earned for the day, but if someone upvotes another one of your answers that day, you'll only get 1 reputation, to bring you back up to the 200 reputation cap.

Comment: This makes sense and is a great explanation ... except that the user's reputation list does not show any negative rep for that entire day! So I'm not sure how that odd number really happened.

Comment: But the fact that there is a 200 point cap DOES explain it.  I just didn't get the other nine points? I think.  I have, in the past down-voted things so I didn't start at an even number.   Thanks for the help.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun As I understand it, downvotes that you make on someone else's answers or questions do not show up on the reputation list to anyone else.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun I found an answer that deserved a down-vote, that I hadn't previously voted on.  Please check if you can see a -1 reputation for me today.  I suspect you won't see it.

Comment: @Beofett you are right, I don't see a -1 in your rep list for today! That makes your answer complete - you rock!